# split field/value from xml STRING not formatted

Tags: c#, split

I have one string in format of XML, (this is not well-formatted XML!) and I would like to get the field and value

```
 <MYXML
address="rua sao carlos, 128" telefone= "1000-222" service="xxxxxx" source="xxxxxxx" username="aaaaaaa" password="122222" nome="asasas" sobrenome="aass" email="sao.aaaaa@aaaaa.com.br" pais="SS" telefone="4002-" />
```

I would like to get the parameter and value separeted in split.

I try this:

```
xml.ToString().Replace(" =" , "=").Replace("= " , "=").Replace(" = " , "=").Split(new char[]{' '});
```

But not work perfect becase for example the attribute 'address' was split in two items

```
{string[29]}
[0]: "<signature"
[1]: "aaa=\"xxxx\""
[2]: "sss=\"xxxx\""
[3]: "ssss=\"xxx\""
[4]: "username=\"xxx\""
[5]: "password=\"xxxx\""
[6]: "nome=\"xxxx\""
[7]: "sobrenome=\"xxx\""
[8]: "email=\"xxx.xxx@xxx.com.br\""
[9]: "pais=\"BR\""
[10]: "endereco=\"Rua"
[11]: "Sao"
[12]: "Carlos,"
[13]: "128\""
[14]: "cidade=\"Sao"
[15]: "Paulo\""
```

The error is

```
   [10]: "endereco=\"Rua"
[11]: "Sao"
[12]: "Carlos,"
```

When the correct I would like is

```
[10]: "endereco=\"Rua Sao Carlos , 128"
```

Comment: That is correct because the address is separtated by ' ' and u wanted to split with ' '

Comment: Can you just rename the duplicate attribute and then parse as well-formatted XML?

Comment: Not becase this xml is diferent in some times. And not have one xml pattern,(one schemma)

Comment: So there are other reasons why the XML is not well-formed?

Comment: Yes, It is create from another company that's not know the 'schemma xml'.

Comment: Well a schema just _validates_ XML.  You can parse XML that's not _validated_, but XML parsers will not parse XML that's not _well-formed_.  I would encourage the provider to give you well-formed XML if at all possible.

Comment: Is not possible to create one pattern to split field/value? I not find anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression will work for this as you are working with badly formed xml.

```
        Regex regex = new Regex("\\s\\w+=\"(\\w|\\s|,|=|@|-|\\.)+\"");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(searchText);
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
          //your code here
        }
```

Tested with your example string and matches were as expected.
Hope this Helps!

Comment: Given that he is working with junk xml, this is the best choice.  +1  Hope he can get good xml tho, then XDocument is the way to go.

Comment: thanks, and I agree that the best result would be to have good xml.

Comment: Hi, your solution it's work perfect AFrieze! I agree it's the best Approach! thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped!  Mark as answer? :)  (green checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use xPath or Linq to parse this xml.  The way you are using is not a good way and that is why you end up in error."Rua Sao Carlo" contains three words separated by single space ; as a result when you try to split it with single space, it also splits the address

Comment: There are multiple `telefone` attributes so it is not well-formed XML.

Comment: I know that is not  well-formed . Becase this is a STRING and not have one "schema xml".

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, you have badly formed XML.  If you were to fix it, by either renaming or removing on of the telephone attributes, you could break down your XML like this:

This is the correct way to handle the XML, if however you do not have control over getting proper xml and must work w/ junk, i'd suggest the regex answer by @AFrieze.

```
var xmlString = @"<MYXML address=""rua sao carlos, 128"" service=""xxxxxx"" source=""xxxxxxx"" username=""aaaaaaa"" password=""122222"" nome=""asasas"" sobrenome=""aass"" email=""sao.aaaaa@aaaaa.com.br"" pais=""SS"" telefone=""4002-"" />";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var values = xml.Descendants("MYXML").SelectMany(x => x.Attributes()).ToArray();

foreach (var value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
Console.Read();
```

This returns:

```
address="rua sao carlos, 128"
service="xxxxxx"
source="xxxxxxx"
username="aaaaaaa"
password="122222"
nome="asasas"
sobrenome="aass"
email="sao.aaaaa@aaaaa.com.br"
pais="SS"
telefone="4002-"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload of `Split`. It will allow you to use a string as the splitter token, namely `'" '` (that is quote and space). This will split to the name and attribute pairs. Then take the resulting array, and split it again on `=` (equals) to get the pairs you need, then do as you will with them. Hope this gets you headed in the right direction